# Ending Debugging in Visual Studio 2010 with F5 does not work immediately, what to do?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I started working with the new Visual Studio 2010. One thing in debugging mode is really annoying: When you press F5 to continue without stepping, the program does not continue like it used to do in Visual Studio 2008 and before but it breaks in certain conditions, even the Disassembly was opened once. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

VS breaks when a condition is encountered. There are two kinds of conditions:

1. Exceptions,
2. User-defined break-points or watch-points.

As you are not defining break-points, there must be some exceptions that are causing the break. These exceptions might have been handled differently in your previous VS version.

You can learn about exceptions and the Exceptions Dialog in [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx).

However, you had better examine very carefully why these exceptions were triggered, because they might just be simple bugs in your code that were not detected by the previous VS (or maybe new conditions that didn't previously arrive).

The Disassembly window is shown when no source-code exists at the address. Sometimes when source-code does exist, one needs to right-click the window and pass to source mode.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There were some exceptions I had enabled that can be disabled now. There are less exceptions now. But still there occur disassembly breakpoints that I do not want. Some exceptions in Visual Studio I cannot disable. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I need some more details about these exceptions.